# Aligning three columns towards right side

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to have three columns aligned so that they are all the right side. Here is what I have so far: https://prnt.sc/o5284n
And here is how this is supposed to work: https://prnt.sc/o528y3

I have managed to solve this problem by applying margin to the sides of the images, but this gets really messed as the web page gets smaller.

I have looked into many other option such as float and column gap but this doesn't work for me in this case

```
 <section id="bottom">
  <img src="Appify.png" alt="app" width="310" height="200" class="pad">
  <p class="twenty_f">APPIFY</p>
  <img src="sunflower.jpeg" alt="flower" width="310" height="200" class="pad">
  <p class="twenty_f">SUNFLOWER</p>

  <img src="bokeh.jpeg" alt="bokeh" width="310" height="200" class="pad">

  <p class="twenty_f">BOKEH</p>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for flexbox handles perfectly.

That being said. The problem you are running into is that you don't have a max-width on your bottom-section.

Try adding:

```
section#bottom {
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This will allow your items to be closer together without stretching out too far.

What I suggest though is using the flexbox method. Another thing is you should wrap your images and related text into a div that contains them together. It gives you better responsive control in the end.

I have given you an example that I quickly did on codepen.

[Link to example](https://codepen.io/f1ss1on/pen/KjWBMy)

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful, I didn't know you could actually do that.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't go with `flexbox` approach. Try this:

```css
#bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#bottom div {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="bottom">
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="app" width="310" height="200" class="pad">
    <p class="twenty_f">APPIFY</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="flower" width="310" height="200" class="pad">
    <p class="twenty_f">SUNFLOWER</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="bokeh" width="310" height="200" class="pad">
    <p class="twenty_f">BOKEH</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot :)